# Show the data based on 2 non numerical and a numerical data in 1 line chart in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a data set including complaint numbers for a different sort of loans in different years-months.

I need to plot a line chart that shows the number of complaints with different colored lines for different loan types during the time. 
My data is as following:

```
'Year_Month' 'Issue'                                'Complaints_Count'
201601       Can't repay my loan                    100
201601       Dealing with my lender or servicer     220
201601       Getting a loan                         13
201602       Can't repay my loan                    113
201602       Dealing with my lender or servicer     252
201602       Getting a loan                         11
201603       Can't repay my loan                    180
201603       Dealing with my lender or servicer     630
201603       Getting a loan                         7
201604       Can't repay my loan                    237
```

My x axis should be 'Year_Month' and the values which should be shown on the line chart are stored in 'Complaints_Count'. There should be a different line for different 'issue'.(issue types will be shown in the legend to determine each line's issue name).

I have been unable to find a solution elsewhere so I'd appreciate if someone could help me with plotting mentioned data.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Users are expected to [attempt to solve their own problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking for help here, do try to use other resources before taking someone elses time to help you.  :)

Comment: why did you think that I asked my questions without searching?! I am a beginner, so maybe I searched incorrectly or maybe I couldn't find my result because of being a beginner and having no knowledge about appropriate keywords...I searched a lot and I couldn't find my answer, hence I asked it here:(

Comment: I didn't mean to offend but your question doesn't give any indication that you tried previously.  In that case know that people (like me ;) may give you heck for not showing your effort but otherwise it looks like you did everything correctly. :D Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is ideally suited for this kind of task.

First, load your data in a panda dataframe. For example, if you have your data in csv format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename.txt)
```

then plot using seaborn:

```
sns.factorplot(data=df, x="Year_Month", y="Complaints_Count", hue="Issue")
```

[image]

There are many options you can use to tweak your plot. Check out the [full documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html#seaborn.factorplot) on `factorplot()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. Actually I am trying to install Seaborn via  'pip install seaborn' but I always get following vague error: failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bsndnm2j\scipy\. I will fix it and then check your offered solution :)